# A proving question based on greatest integer function.

Tags: functions, special-functions

If $$[x]=[\frac{x}{2}]+[\frac{x+1}{2}] $$b , where [°] denotes the greatest integer function and $n$ be a positive integer, then show that 
$$[\frac{n+1}{2}]+[\frac{n+2}{4}]+[\frac{n+4}{8}]+[\frac{n+8}{16}]\cdots = n$$.
I tried to solve this problem by removing the integer parts and then adding the left over parts but could not get the result please help me out.

Comment: Shouldn't there be "+" in between?

Comment: Check it for small values of $n$ and you will see the pattern.

Comment: A reason for saying "+" instead of "*" is simply because at least the last one of those integral parts will be zero (simply by limit of the above series), giving you $0$ on multiplication!

Answer (score 1):

$$[n]=[\frac{n}{2}]+[\frac{n+1}{2}]$$
$$[\frac{n}{2}]=[\frac{n}{4}]+[\frac{\frac{n}{2}+1}{2}]=[\frac{n}{4}]+[\frac{n+2}{4}]$$
$$[\frac{n}{4}]=[\frac{n}{8}]+[\frac{\frac{n}{4}+1}{2}]=[\frac{n}{8}]+[\frac{n+4}{8}]$$
and so on.
Use telescopic sums to get the answer ;).